# Is there a way to have an action with detail = True inside another action with detail = True in Django rest?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

My user model has a Many to one relationship to a Clothes model and inside my User viewset I created an extra action to list the Clothes instances in relation to a specific user

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['get'], serializer_class=UserOutfitSerializer)
def outfit (self, request, pk=None):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    clothes = user.clothes_set.all()
    serializer = UserOutfitSerializer(user.clothes_set.all(), many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

It's possible to make another extra action to retrive/update/delete each instance clothes for that user ('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/user_id/outfit/clothes_id') and if it is, would that be a bad pratice?

Comment: Yes it is possible to make other extra actions. You can just change the methods. 
But better to update/retrieve/delete from separate URL. You might have OutFitViewSet and default router set to it. You can use that URL to update/retrieve/delete. The action @outfit will provide you the required uuid or pk, you can use that to update/retieve/delete from your model.

Answer (score 0):

You could add more action that mocked the name of your listing action and replace the default action url_path with a "detail in detail" you want.

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['GET'], url_path=r'outfit/(?P<cloth_id>\d+)')
def outfit_retrieve(self, request, pk, cloth_id):
    user = self.get_object()
    cloth = get_object_or_404(user.clothes_set.all(), id=cloth_id)
    serializer = UserOutfitSerializer(cloth)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

@action(detail=True, methods=['POST'], url_path=r'outfit/(?P<cloth_id>\d+)')
def outfit_add(self, request, pk, cloth_id):
    user = self.get_object()
    cloth = get_object_or_404(Cloth.objects.all(), id=cloth_id)
    user.clothes_set.add(cloth)
    serializer = UserOutfitSerializer(cloth)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```